# Looking for SQL tutorials for beginner

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, mysql-spatial

Where can I get quality tutorials on learning SQL for GIS?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you should start searching the web first.

Comment: How do you define quality?

Answer (score 3):

On the PostGIS website, in training material, there is a complete guide to learn about Spatial queries and how use PostGIS : https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/